# Kafka consumer message consumption delayed for one VM in cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have a cluster running kafka 10.2.1 in which a kafka message is sent using kafka-console-producer.sh and 2/3 subscribers receive the message immediately, yet the other receives the message significantly later (4 minutes). I'm assuming this is an issue with the subscriber, so below is my subscriber config

```
protected ConsumerFactory<String, Object> createConsumerFactory(String kafkaBrokers) {
  Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
  return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}


protected KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> createKafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory) {
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
  factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
  factory.setConcurrency(1);
  factory.setAutoStartup(true);
  factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
  factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
  return factory;
}
```

The subscribers are running in Java Spring JVM but the producer is a simple python script which invokes kafka-console-producer.sh to send message. The producer config is default. What could cause the message to be arriving so late?

Not sure if relevant - When I do `ls -l` on kafka folder dump log segments (kafka/myTopic-0/), I see that 000000...000.log has already been written to the late VM at the time I expect, leading me to believe the message was delivered on time. Yet Java subscriber picks up message later. What can be the reason?

Comment: It could be the consumer waiting for MinBytes to arrive before MaxWaitTime arrives. If the throughput is low, try setting MaxWaitTime to zero and MinBytes to 1. [More here](https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net/issues/44)

Comment: Thanks. maxWaitTime defaults to 500 milliseconds though which doesn't explain 4 seconds delay...

Comment: Pity. Do you mean 4 minutes (as per title)? That is huge latency.

Comment: Yes I do, sorry for typo. Meant to say 4 minutes

Comment: could it have something to do with max.poll.interval.ms?